# enable ARM mode in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, assembly, arm

I'm trying to compile the following code in Xcode 4.4. I know that to enable the compiler to recognize the _asm keyword that I must enable ARM compilation on this file and I believe that to do that I must add -marm to the compiler flags to this translation unit. Does anyone know how to do this in Xcode. Is this right? and does anyone know the way to do it in Xcode 4.4?

```
_asm volatile 
(
 // Store A & B leaving room for q4-q7, which should be preserved
 "vldmia %1, { q0-q3 } \n\t"
 "vldmia %2, { q8-q11 }\n\t"

 // result = first column of B x first row of A
 "vmul.f32 q12, q8, d0[0]\n\t"
 "vmul.f32 q13, q8, d2[0]\n\t"
 "vmul.f32 q14, q8, d4[0]\n\t"
 "vmul.f32 q15, q8, d6[0]\n\t"

 // result += second column of B x second row of A
 "vmla.f32 q12, q9, d0[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q13, q9, d2[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q14, q9, d4[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q15, q9, d6[1]\n\t"

 // result += third column of B x third row of A
 "vmla.f32 q12, q10, d1[0]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q13, q10, d3[0]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q14, q10, d5[0]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q15, q10, d7[0]\n\t"

 // result += last column of B x last row of A
 "vmla.f32 q12, q11, d1[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q13, q11, d3[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q14, q11, d5[1]\n\t"
 "vmla.f32 q15, q11, d7[1]\n\t"

 // output = result registers
 "vstmia %0, { q12-q15 }"
 : // no output
 : "r" (output), "r" (a), "r" (b)   // input - note *value* of pointer doesn't change
 : "memory", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15" //clobber
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing your assembler in a `.S` source file which will be assembled by the C-compiler and provide pre-processor facilities and also means you don't need to quote everything and Xcode will accept the file without enabling anything at all.

Here's a fragment of a source file I use (it's X86-64, but you get the idea):

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define NAME(name) _##name
#else
#define NAME(name) name
#endif

#define IN_ASM
#include "Asm.h"

.data
.align 8

cpu_caps:   .long   0x0

.text
.align 8

C55:        .quad   0x5555555555555555
C33:        .quad   0x3333333333333333
C0F:        .quad   0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
C01:        .quad   0x0101010101010101

#ifdef __x86_64

.globl NAME(asmInit);
//.type NAME(asmInit), %function
NAME(asmInit):
    pushq %rbx

    movl $1, %eax
    cpuid       // ecx=feature info 1, edx=feature info 2

    xorl %eax, %eax         // prepare return value

    testl $1 << 0, %edx
    jz 1f
    orl $CPUCAP_FPU, %eax

1:
    testl $1 << 23, %edx
    jz 2f
    orl $CPUCAP_MMX, %eax

2:
    testl $1 << 25, %edx
    jz 3f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSE, %eax

3:
    testl $1 << 26, %edx
    jz 4f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSE2, %eax

4:
    testl $1 << 0, %ecx
    jz 5f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSE3, %eax

5:
    testl $1 << 9, %ecx
    jz 6f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSSE3, %eax

6:
    testl $1 << 19, %ecx
    jz 7f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSE4_1, %eax

7:
    testl $1 << 20, %ecx
    jz 8f
    orl $CPUCAP_SSE4_2, %eax

8:
    testl $1 << 23, %ecx
    jz 9f
    orl $CPUCAP_POPCNT, %eax

9:
    movl %eax, cpu_caps(%rip)

    movl $1, %eax           // return true
    popq %rbx
    ret
```